# Module loading issue in Ruby

Tags: ruby, class, module, object-oriented-analysis

I have a situation where I can access a module's functions from one file but not another. These files are both in the same directory. I'll try to recreate the code the best I can:

Directory Structure:

```
init.rb
lib/FileGenerator.rb
lib/AutoConfig.rb
lib/modules/helpers.rb
```

lib/AutoConfig.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'filegenerator'
require 'modules/helpers'

class AutoConfig
  include Helpers

  def initialize
  end

  def myFunction
    myhelper #here's the module function
  end

  def mySecondFunction
    FileGenerator.generatorFunction # call to the FileGenerator
  end
end
```

lib/FileGenerator.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'modules/helpers'

class FileGenerator
  include Helpers

  def initialize
  end

  def self.generatorFunction
    myhelper #here's the module function that doesn't work
  end
end
```

lib/modules/helper.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

module Helpers
    def myhelper
      #Do Stuff
    end
end
```

The AutoConfig file is the main workhorse of the app. When it calls to the `myhelper` module function it gives me no problems what-so-ever. The AutoConfig part way through calls the `FileGenerator.generatorFunction`.

The `FileGenerator.generatorFunction` also contains this same module function, but for some reason when I run the program I get the following error:

```
filegenerator.rb:26:in `generatorFunction': undefined method `myhelper' for FileGenerator:Class (NoMethodError)
```

I've been at this now for several hours trying many different combinations and can't figure out where I'm going wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`generatorFunction` is a class method. It doesn't see instance-level methods. And `myhelper` (brought in by `include Helpers`) is an instance method. To remedy that, you should `extend Helpers` instead. It works like `include`, but makes class methods.

```
class FileGenerator
  extend Helpers

end
```

BTW, the name `generatorFunction` is not in ruby style. You should name methods in snake_case (`generator_function`).

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo in transcription. Updated the question

Comment: That was the problem! Thank you very much, and I'll make sure to change the method names!